# How to access a fully qualified domain name through "localhost"?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, nginx, dns, environment-variables

About nine minutes into a [tutorial](https://youtu.be/_08L9pubPCY) on `ERPNext` I followed directions as:

```
root@mordor:/home/nicholas/git/frappe_docker# 
root@mordor:/home/nicholas/git/frappe_docker# cat .env
LETSENCRYPT_EMAIL=nicholas@mordor.bounceme.net
ERPNEXT_VERSION=edge
FRAPPE_VERSION=edge
MARIADB_HOST=mariadb
MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=admin
SITE_NAME=erp.mordor.bounceme.net
SITES=`erp.mordor.bounceme.net`
DB_ROOT_USER=root
ADMIN_PASSWORD=admin
INSTALL_APPS=erpnext
ENTRYPOINT_LABEL=traefik.http.routers.erpnext-nginx.entrypoints=websecure
CERT_RESOLVER_LABEL=traefik.http.routers.erpnext-nginx.tls.certresolver=myresolver
HTTPS_REDIRECT_RULE_LABEL=traefik.http.routers.http-catchall.rule=hostregexp(`{host:.+}`)
HTTPS_REDIRECT_ENTRYPOINT_LABEL=traefik.http.routers.http-catchall.entrypoints=web
HTTPS_REDIRECT_MIDDLEWARE_LABEL=traefik.http.routers.http-catchall.middlewares=redirect-to-https
HTTPS_USE_REDIRECT_MIDDLEWARE_LABEL=traefik.http.middlewares.redirect-to-https.redirectscheme.scheme=https
root@mordor:/home/nicholas/git/frappe_docker# 
root@mordor:/home/nicholas/git/frappe_docker# docker-compose up -d
Creating network "frappe_docker_default" with the default driver
Creating volume "frappe_docker_redis-cache-vol" with default driver
Creating volume "frappe_docker_cert-vol" with default driver
Creating volume "frappe_docker_redis-queue-vol" with default driver
Creating volume "frappe_docker_mariadb-vol" with default driver
Creating volume "frappe_docker_redis-socketio-vol" with default driver
Creating volume "frappe_docker_sites-vol" with default driver
Creating volume "frappe_docker_assets-vol" with default driver
Pulling erpnext-python (frappe/erpnext-worker:edge)...
edge: Pulling from frappe/erpnext-worker
Digest: sha256:45e7fb925187bc6ed71ca8db2bd886a8cbcfb7714197b7f140fb479469bc3c98
Status: Downloaded newer image for frappe/erpnext-worker:edge
Pulling mariadb (mariadb:10.3)...
10.3: Pulling from library/mariadb
6a5697faee43: Pull complete
ba13d3bc422b: Pull complete
a254829d9e55: Pull complete
2ee2cadd29fc: Pull complete
6915a184049d: Pull complete
5ca6ffdb5f56: Pull complete
1537f7bbef8b: Pull complete
5790e54322d1: Pull complete
ea98cb829471: Pull complete
3247072bad5f: Pull complete
b3f16e2db43f: Pull complete
d78c54af82d5: Pull complete
b08843faa954: Pull complete
Digest: sha256:69dec37e0651252108d61ac87874ed8d83b74ead38d196b0bb10d784b7295e8b
Status: Downloaded newer image for mariadb:10.3
Pulling frappe-socketio (frappe/frappe-socketio:edge)...
edge: Pulling from frappe/frappe-socketio
babf97a3f00a: Pull complete
d81eb1809d95: Pull complete
d50e90677ab1: Pull complete
4ca478941ba5: Pull complete
cac0c8c03bb1: Pull complete
55aedfc1b65f: Pull complete
1bee561a211c: Pull complete
fab9a623660f: Pull complete
7b5f157fcbc6: Pull complete
e5f74c3ab32d: Pull complete
6f1760dc7d35: Pull complete
f9389a9f5f4c: Pull complete
Digest: sha256:dfe6dc1d2ffb824f04dc2cd620327f75355620ba657865ee98441c88b8596ed5
Status: Downloaded newer image for frappe/frappe-socketio:edge
Pulling traefik (traefik:v2.2)...
v2.2: Pulling from library/traefik
cbdbe7a5bc2a: Pull complete
f16506d32a25: Pull complete
605303653d66: Pull complete
a9005a35b171: Pull complete
Digest: sha256:ea0aa8832bfd08369166baecd40b35fc58979df8f5dc5182e4e63ee6adbe66db
Status: Downloaded newer image for traefik:v2.2
Pulling erpnext-nginx (frappe/erpnext-nginx:edge)...
edge: Pulling from frappe/erpnext-nginx
bb79b6b2107f: Pull complete
5a9f1c0027a7: Pull complete
b5c20b2b484f: Pull complete
166a2418f7e8: Pull complete
1966ea362d23: Pull complete
3915f6e86363: Pull complete
f6bb7178bcfb: Pull complete
44ac8c313cd6: Pull complete
07bf0268acb1: Pull complete
2b15c776928e: Pull complete
58517104a340: Pull complete
44e719acaf68: Pull complete
f16420799ad5: Pull complete
Digest: sha256:d7031e28b62d0e67eae432937902fe618d32709039a1d63199598881ed5c6459
Status: Downloaded newer image for frappe/erpnext-nginx:edge
Creating frappe_docker_redis-cache_1     ... done
Creating frappe_docker_erpnext-nginx_1  ... done
Creating frappe_docker_mariadb_1        ... done
Creating frappe_docker_erpnext-python_1  ... done
Creating frappe_docker_redis-socketio_1 ... done
Creating frappe_docker_traefik_1                ... done
Creating frappe_docker_redis-queue_1    ... done
Creating frappe_docker_frappe-socketio_1        ... done
Creating frappe_docker_site-creator_1           ... done
Creating frappe_docker_erpnext-schedule_1       ... done
Creating frappe_docker_erpnext-worker-long_1    ... done
Creating frappe_docker_erpnext-worker-default_1 ... done
Creating frappe_docker_erpnext-worker-short_1   ... done
root@mordor:/home/nicholas/git/frappe_docker# 




root@mordor:~# 
root@mordor:~# docker container list
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                         COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                                      NAMES
d150de825277        frappe/erpnext-worker:edge    "docker-entrypoint.s…"   15 minutes ago      Up 15 minutes       8000/tcp                                   frappe_docker_erpnext-worker-short_1
54c716c27275        frappe/erpnext-worker:edge    "docker-entrypoint.s…"   15 minutes ago      Up 15 minutes       8000/tcp                                   frappe_docker_erpnext-worker-default_1
ef73c8514f32        frappe/erpnext-worker:edge    "docker-entrypoint.s…"   15 minutes ago      Up 15 minutes       8000/tcp                                   frappe_docker_erpnext-schedule_1
ce45f0955bac        frappe/erpnext-worker:edge    "docker-entrypoint.s…"   15 minutes ago      Up 15 minutes       8000/tcp                                   frappe_docker_erpnext-worker-long_1
9a3eb0a2f9d2        frappe/erpnext-worker:edge    "docker-entrypoint.s…"   15 minutes ago      Up 15 minutes       8000/tcp                                   frappe_docker_site-creator_1
652280f21336        frappe/frappe-socketio:edge   "docker-entrypoint.s…"   16 minutes ago      Up 15 minutes                                                  frappe_docker_frappe-socketio_1
e6b6c59b01fd        redis:latest                  "docker-entrypoint.s…"   16 minutes ago      Up 16 minutes       6379/tcp                                   frappe_docker_redis-queue_1
c3e0d8c41c08        redis:latest                  "docker-entrypoint.s…"   16 minutes ago      Up 16 minutes       6379/tcp                                   frappe_docker_redis-socketio_1
58cd5b59579c        traefik:v2.2                  "/entrypoint.sh --lo…"   16 minutes ago      Up 15 minutes       0.0.0.0:80->80/tcp, 0.0.0.0:443->443/tcp   frappe_docker_traefik_1
4a4b4caffbec        frappe/erpnext-worker:edge    "docker-entrypoint.s…"   16 minutes ago      Up 15 minutes       8000/tcp                                   frappe_docker_erpnext-python_1
221dd3e1e419        frappe/erpnext-nginx:edge     "/docker-entrypoint.…"   16 minutes ago      Up 14 minutes       80/tcp                                     frappe_docker_erpnext-nginx_1
6100cc729cb1        redis:latest                  "docker-entrypoint.s…"   16 minutes ago      Up 15 minutes       6379/tcp                                   frappe_docker_redis-cache_1
a31d8a43726c        mariadb:10.3                  "docker-entrypoint.s…"   16 minutes ago      Up 16 minutes       3306/tcp                                   frappe_docker_mariadb_1
root@mordor:~#
```

However:

```
nicholas@mordor:~$ 
nicholas@mordor:~$ lynx localhost --dump

Looking up localhost
Making HTTP connection to localhost
Sending HTTP request.
HTTP request sent; waiting for response.
HTTP/1.0 302 Found
Data transfer complete
HTTP/1.0 302 Found
Using https://localhost/
Looking up localhost
Making HTTPS connection to localhost

lynx: Can't access startfile http://localhost/
nicholas@mordor:~$
```

How do I configure as above for local usage?  Effectively, offline.  To my understanding, `nginx` is being used as a reverse proxy here.

I'm getting some result:

```
nicholas@mordor:~$ 
nicholas@mordor:~$ lynx erp.mordor.bounceme.net --dump

nicholas@mordor:~$
```

but not the welcome screen I'm looking for.  The `FQDN` isn't publicly available.

Answer (score 2):

According to your screen dump you have your port 80 mapped to the Traefik container

`58cd5b59579c        traefik:v2.2                  "/entrypoint.sh --lo…"   16 minutes ago      Up 15 minutes       0.0.0.0:80->80/tcp, 0.0.0.0:443->443/tcp   frappe_docker_traefik_1`

The listen address of this mapping is `0.0.0.0` on both port `80 HTTP`, and `443 HTTPS` which means it listens on all your computer interfaces. Including the local-loopback interface which has the address of `127.0.0.1`.

Most operating systems have a file called `hosts` which is located at `/etc/hosts` for Linux, MacOS, BSD and at `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts` for Windows 10.

This file maps the DNS names (such as `localhost`) to their IP addresses, like `127.0.0.1`.

For you to have a working `FQDN`, you can temporarily create a new mapping in this file to map your desired name to the local-loopback address of 127.0.0.1.

Edit the `hosts` file and add a line saying:

```
127.0.0.1 erp.mordor.bounceme.net
```

The applications that lookup that name later, such as `lynx`, will now know that `erp.mordor.bounceme.net` is located at `127.0.0.1` IP address. And your Docker Traefik container is listening there (as well) on ports `80` and `443`.

Comment: yes, I've configured this.  It seems to be a `traefik` configuration problem:  https://devops.stackexchange.com/q/12762/23443